# Использование typename

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста:

Почему такой код компилируется в MSVC 2012 без ошибок, несмотря на использование *typename* :

```
#include "stdafx.h" // нужно для MSVC
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct A
{
    void g()
    {
        int x = 5;
        {
            // если T::iterator - шаблон, принимающий числовой аргумент,
            // это инстанциация шаблона в переменную x, перекрывающую x
            // за фигурными скобками
            // если T::iterator -- экземпляр класса с перегруженным оператором <,
            // это сравнение T::iterator с нулём, а затем сравнение результата
            // со значением переменной x!
            typename T::iterator<0> x; //ВОТ ЭТА СТРОКА
        }
    }
};

struct T3
{
    template<int C> struct iterator
    {
        iterator() { cout << "constructing template with C = " << C << endl; }
    };
};

struct T4
{
    struct Titerator
    {
        Titerator operator < (int value)
        {
            cout << "in operator < " << value << endl;
            return Titerator();
        }
        bool operator > (int value)
        {
            cout << "in operator > " <<  value << endl;
            return false;
        }
    };
    static Titerator iterator;
};

T4::Titerator T4::iterator = T4::Titerator();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A<T3> a3; a3.g();
    A<T4> a4; a4.g();
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает следующий результат:

```
constructing template with C = 0
in operator < 0
in operator > 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О, знакомый код :) Дело в том, что MSVC не вполне корректно реализует стандарт для обратной совместимости со старым кодом, а также, насколько я понимаю, для нужд собственных библиотек (SDK), и компилирует этот код даже в ANSI-режиме (`/Za /Wall`). GCC, например, этот код [не компилирует](http://ideone.com/PBe5Pa).